# how to repeat taxonomy in different places on wordpress

Tags: plugins, functions, query-posts, actions

I need help with this.
I need repeat taxonomy in two places, are post, and coupones post, this code is in clipper theme.

this code put taxonomy stores in coupon.

```
add_action('init', 'clpr_post_type', 0);
// remove_action('init', 'create_builtin_taxonomies', 0); // in case we want to remove all default WP taxonomies
// register all the custom taxonomies and custom post type
function clpr_post_type() {
  global $wpdb, $app_abbr; //need $wpdb!!

// get the slug value for the ad custom post type & taxonomies
  if(get_option($app_abbr.'_coupon_permalink')) $post_type_base_url = get_option($app_abbr.'_coupon_permalink'); else $post_type_base_url = 'coupon';
  if(get_option($app_abbr.'_coupon_cat_tax_permalink')) $cat_tax_base_url = get_option($app_abbr.'_coupon_cat_tax_permalink'); else $cat_tax_base_url = 'coupon-category';
  if(get_option($app_abbr.'_coupon_type_tax_permalink')) $type_tax_base_url = get_option($app_abbr.'_coupon_type_tax_permalink'); else $type_tax_base_url = 'coupon-type';
  if(get_option($app_abbr.'_coupon_store_tax_permalink')) $store_tax_base_url = get_option($app_abbr.'_coupon_store_tax_permalink'); else $store_tax_base_url = 'store';
  if(get_option($app_abbr.'_coupon_tag_tax_permalink')) $tag_tax_base_url = get_option($app_abbr.'_coupon_tag_tax_permalink'); else $tag_tax_base_url = 'coupon-tag';
  if(get_option($app_abbr.'_coupon_image_tax_permalink')) $image_tax_base_url = get_option($app_abbr.'_coupon_image_tax_permalink'); else $image_tax_base_url = 'coupon-image';

  register_post_type( APP_POST_TYPE,
    array(  'labels' => array(
     'name' => __( 'Coupons', 'appthemes' ),
     'singular_name' => __( 'Coupons', 'appthemes' ),     
     'add_new' => __( 'Add New', 'appthemes' ),
     'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Coupon', 'appthemes' ),
     'edit' => __( 'Edit', 'appthemes' ),
     'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Coupon', 'appthemes' ),
     'new_item' => __( 'New Coupon', 'appthemes' ),
     'view' => __( 'View Coupons', 'appthemes' ),
     'view_item' => __( 'View Coupon', 'appthemes' ),
     'search_items' => __( 'Search Coupons', 'appthemes' ),
     'not_found' => __( 'No coupons found', 'appthemes' ),
     'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No coupons found in trash', 'appthemes' ),
     'parent' => __( 'Parent Coupon', 'appthemes' ),
     ),
    'description' => __( 'This is where you can create new coupon listings on your site.', 'appthemes' ),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'menu_position' => 8,
    'menu_icon' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/site_icon.png',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => $post_type_base_url, 'with_front' => false ), /* Slug set so that permalinks work when just showing post name */
    'query_var' => true,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'sticky' )
    )
        );

    // register post status for unreliable coupons
        register_post_status( 'unreliable', 
          array(  'label' => __( 'Unreliable', 'appthemes' ),
            'public' => true,
            '_builtin' => true,
            'label_count' => _n_noop( 'Unreliable <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Unreliable <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'appthemes' ),
            'show_in_admin_all_list' => true,
            'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
            'capability_type' => APP_POST_TYPE,
            )
          );

    // register the newcategory taxonomy
        register_taxonomy( APP_TAX_CAT,
          array( APP_POST_TYPE ),
          array(  'hierarchical' => true,
            'labels' => array(
             'name' => __( 'Categories', 'appthemes'),
             'singular_name' => __( 'Coupon Category', 'appthemes'),
             'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Coupon Categories', 'appthemes'),
             'all_items' => __( 'All Coupon Categories', 'appthemes'),
             'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Coupon Category', 'appthemes'),
             'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Coupon Category:', 'appthemes'),
             'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Coupon Category', 'appthemes'),
             'update_item' => __( 'Update Coupon Category', 'appthemes'),
             'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Coupon Category', 'appthemes'),
             'new_item_name' => __( 'New Coupon Category Name', 'appthemes')
             ),
            'show_ui' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => $cat_tax_base_url, 'with_front' => false, 'hierarchical' => true ), 
            )
        );

        register_taxonomy( APP_TAX_TAG,
          array( APP_POST_TYPE ),
          array(  'hierarchical' => false,
            'labels' => array(
              'name' => __( 'Coupon Tags', 'appthemes'),
              'singular_name' => __( 'Coupon Tag', 'appthemes'),
              'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Coupon Tags', 'appthemes'),
              'all_items' => __( 'All Coupon Tags', 'appthemes'),
              'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Coupon Tag', 'appthemes'),
              'update_item' => __( 'Update Coupon Tag', 'appthemes'),
              'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Coupon Tag', 'appthemes'),
              'add_or_remove_items' => __( 'Add or remove Coupon Tags', 'appthemes'),
              'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate Coupon Tags with commas', 'appthemes'),
              'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Choose from the most common Coupon Tags', 'appthemes'),
              'new_item_name' => __( 'New Coupon Tag Name', 'appthemes')
              ),
            'show_ui' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => $tag_tax_base_url, 'with_front' => false, 'hierarchical' => true ), 
            )
        );

        register_taxonomy( APP_TAX_STORE,
          array( APP_POST_TYPE ),
          array(  'hierarchical' => true,
            'labels' => array(
              'name' => __( 'Stores', 'appthemes'),
              'singular_name' => __( 'Store', 'appthemes'),
              'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Stores', 'appthemes'),
              'all_items' => __( 'All Stores', 'appthemes'),
              'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Store', 'appthemes'),
              'update_item' => __( 'Update Store', 'appthemes'),
              'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Store', 'appthemes'),
              'add_or_remove_items' => __( 'Add or remove Stores', 'appthemes'),
              'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate Stores with commas', 'appthemes'),
              'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Choose from the most common Stores', 'appthemes'),
              'new_item_name' => __( 'New Store Name', 'appthemes')
              ),
            'show_ui' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => $store_tax_base_url, 'with_front' => false, 'hierarchical' => true ),
            )
        );

        register_taxonomy( APP_TAX_TYPE,
          array( APP_POST_TYPE ),
          array(  'hierarchical' => true,
            'labels' => array(
              'name' => __( 'Coupon Types', 'appthemes'),
              'singular_name' => __( 'Coupon Type', 'appthemes'),
              'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Coupon Types', 'appthemes'),
              'all_items' => __( 'All Coupon Types', 'appthemes'),
              'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Coupon Type', 'appthemes'),
              'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Coupon Type:', 'appthemes'),
              'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Coupon Type', 'appthemes'),
              'update_item' => __( 'Update Coupon Type', 'appthemes'),
              'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Coupon Type', 'appthemes'),
              'new_item_name' => __( 'New Coupon Type Name', 'appthemes')
              ),
            'show_ui' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => $type_tax_base_url, 'with_front' => false, 'hierarchical' => true ),
            )
        );

    // register taxonomy for printable coupon images
        register_taxonomy( APP_TAX_IMAGE,
          array( 'attachment' ),
          array(  'hierarchical' => false,
            'labels' => array(
              'name' => __( 'Coupon Images', 'appthemes'),
              'singular_name' => __( 'Coupon Image', 'appthemes'),
              'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Coupon Images', 'appthemes'),
              'all_items' => __( 'All Coupon Images', 'appthemes'),
              'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Coupon Image', 'appthemes'),
              'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Coupon Image:', 'appthemes'),
              'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Coupon Image', 'appthemes'),
              'update_item' => __( 'Update Coupon Image', 'appthemes'),
              'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Coupon Image', 'appthemes'),
              'new_item_name' => __( 'New Coupon Image Name', 'appthemes')
              ),
            'public' => false,
            'show_ui' => false,
            'query_var' => true,
            'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => $image_tax_base_url, 'with_front' => false, 'hierarchical' => false ),
            )
        );

        $wpdb->storesmeta = $wpdb->clpr_storesmeta;

  // this needs to happen once after install script first runs
        if ( get_option( $app_abbr.'_rewrite_flush_flag' ) == 'true' ) {
          flush_rewrite_rules();
          delete_option( $app_abbr.'_rewrite_flush_flag' );
        }

      }
```

and this is my code in the same file.

```
// new code taxonomias
function clrp_taxonomy_post(){

    global $wpdb, $app_abbr; //need $wpdb!!
    if(get_option($app_abbr.'_coupon_store_tax_permalink')) $store_tax_base_url = get_option($app_abbr.'_coupon_store_tax_permalink'); else $store_tax_base_url = 'store';

    register_taxonomy( APP_TAX_STORE, // taxonomy stores
        array( APP_POST_TYPE_POST ), // type POST
        array(  'hierarchical' => true,
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Stores', 'appthemes'),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Store', 'appthemes'),
                'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Stores', 'appthemes'),
                'all_items' => __( 'All Stores', 'appthemes'),
                'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Store', 'appthemes'),
                'update_item' => __( 'Update Store', 'appthemes'),
                'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Store', 'appthemes'),
                'add_or_remove_items' => __( 'Add or remove Stores', 'appthemes'),
                'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate Stores with commas', 'appthemes'),
                'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Choose from the most common Stores', 'appthemes'),
                'new_item_name' => __( 'New Store Name', 'appthemes')
            ),
            'show_ui' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => $store_tax_base_url, 'with_front' => false, 'hierarchical' => true ),
        )
    );
}

add_action('init', 'clrp_taxonomy_post', 0);
```

this last code just show in post but not in coupons, I need to this taxonomy show in post and coupons

thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
register_taxonomy( 'taxonomy', array( 'post', 'coupons' ), $args );
```

https://generatewp.com/taxonomy/ can help you.

```
// new code taxonomias
function clrp_taxonomy_post(){

    global $wpdb, $app_abbr; //need $wpdb!!
    if(get_option($app_abbr.'_coupon_store_tax_permalink')) $store_tax_base_url = get_option($app_abbr.'_coupon_store_tax_permalink'); else $store_tax_base_url = 'store';

    register_taxonomy( APP_TAX_STORE, // taxonomy stores
        array( APP_POST_TYPE_POST, APP_POST_TYPE ), // type POST + APP_POST_TYPE 
        array(  'hierarchical' => true,
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Stores', 'appthemes'),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Store', 'appthemes'),
                'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Stores', 'appthemes'),
                'all_items' => __( 'All Stores', 'appthemes'),
                'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Store', 'appthemes'),
                'update_item' => __( 'Update Store', 'appthemes'),
                'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Store', 'appthemes'),
                'add_or_remove_items' => __( 'Add or remove Stores', 'appthemes'),
                'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate Stores with commas', 'appthemes'),
                'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Choose from the most common Stores', 'appthemes'),
                'new_item_name' => __( 'New Store Name', 'appthemes')
            ),
            'show_ui' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => $store_tax_base_url, 'with_front' => false, 'hierarchical' => true ),
        )
    );
}

add_action('init', 'clrp_taxonomy_post', 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The second argument of [`register_taxonomy`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) is the object type you want it associated with. Right now it is:

```
array( APP_POST_TYPE_POST )
```

change it to:

```
array( APP_POST_TYPE_POST, APP_POST_TYPE )
```

You can also use [`register_taxonomy_for_object_type`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy_for_object_type) to accomplish this, or the `taxonomies` argument of [`register_post_type`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type).